# how get no border effect in tkinter ttk?

Tags: python, tkinter, border, tk-toolkit, ttk

[image]

To get button no border effect in tkinter tk I used to set `borderwidth=0`. Button will merge into background. But I can't get same effect in tkinter ttk. I set `borderwidth=0` in style. Button always have borderwidth. I don't know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by setting the button relief to `flat` or borderwidth to 0 using a ttk style. However, some ttk themes don't take into account these style settings, and one of them is the default theme in Windows. Setting the theme to 'clam' or 'alt' should solve your problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='tk.Button', borderwidth=0)
b1.pack()

s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('flat.TButton', borderwidth=0)
# s.configure('flat.TButton', relief='flat') gives the same result

b2 = ttk.Button(root, style='flat.TButton', text='ttk.Button')
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank u for your reply,I try your code,no effect,ttk button always have border

Comment: @Pythonrookie It may depend on system. On Linux it works.

Comment: @Python rookie, try to add `s.theme_use('clam')`. I think the effect is theme dependent and that default windows theme does not support flat buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the border on windows or osx. The whole point of using ttk buttons on those platforms is to get native widgets. If you want a button without a border, use the standard tk button.

Comment: The answer by @j_4321 above does remove the border of ttk buttons, at least so far on windows.