# How to get FLAT relief Entry widget in python ttk?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I am writing a GUI FTP client app in python ttk. I can't seem to get the text Entries the way I wanted them to.[image]

The text Entries have the "SUNKEN" effect. I want to adjust the height and get the text entries to have a "FLAT" look, more like this program:
[image]

I got the buttons to look flat from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990704/how-get-no-border-effect-in-tkinter-ttk), I am struggling to get the Entries to look flat.
How do I get the Entries to look flat?
I don't want a tk solution, I know how to set relief FLAT in tk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Trivia:

Appereance of ttk widgets heavily depends on theme in use and/or platform. On windows I can reproduce this depressive gray style with a `classic` theme, so let's assume that this theme in use. List of themes you can find [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/48689) (note the `'clam'` theme, wich is most similar to your wishes), just if you wonder.

Next stop, our [`layout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.layout) or, in other words, [a structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#layouts) of widget's theme.
You can easily print this structure to see available options. Enough words, let's try a structure of an `ttk.Entry` widget.

```
>>> print(s.layout('TEntry'))

#   formatted result, actual result is one-line string
[('Entry.highlight', {
    'sticky': 'nswe',
    'children': [(
        'Entry.field', {
            'sticky': 'nswe',
            'children': [(
                'Entry.padding', {
                    'sticky': 'nswe',
                    'children': [(
                        'Entry.textarea', {
                            'sticky': 'nswe'})]
                })],
            'border': '1'})]
})]
```

[As you can see](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.element_options), noone of structure elements has a `relief` option, hence `relief='flat'` has no effect on our entry!

```
>>> print(s.element_options('Entry.field'))
('-bordercolor', '-lightcolor', '-darkcolor', '-fieldbackground')
```

### Workaround:

However, we can edit the layout of desired widget, and replace one element with another, wich able to recognize a `relief` option (note a removed `Entry.field`, replaced with an `Entry.border`).

So try out this little snippet:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

#   root
root = tk.Tk()

#   declare style variable
s = ttk.Style()
#   assume that classic theme in use
s.theme_use('classic')

#   configure relief
s.configure('SOExample.TEntry', relief='flat')

#   lets try to change this structure
s.layout('SOExample.TEntry', [
    ('Entry.highlight', {
        'sticky': 'nswe',
        'children':
            [('Entry.border', {
                'border': '1',
                'sticky': 'nswe',
                'children':
                    [('Entry.padding', {
                        'sticky': 'nswe',
                        'children':
                            [('Entry.textarea',
                              {'sticky': 'nswe'})]
                    })]
            })]
    })])

#   let's find some differences between this two
print(s.layout('SOExample.TEntry'))
print(s.layout('TEntry'))

#    packing
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text='Flat Entry')
entry1 = ttk.Entry(frame1, style='SOExample.TEntry')
label1.pack()
entry1.pack()
frame1.pack(side='left')

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text='Default Entry')
entry2 = ttk.Entry(frame2)
label2.pack()
entry2.pack()
frame2.pack(side='right')

#   mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

...and final appereance is:

[image: non-active][image: active]

Also, on my machine default theme is `vista` and there I can't even recognize an entry:
[image: vista]

And also a structure of an `Entry` depends on theme, so with `vista` it's:

```
#   formatted result, actual result is one-line string
[('Entry.field', {
    'sticky': 'nswe',
    'children': [(
        'Entry.background', {
            'sticky': 'nswe',
            'children': [(
                'Entry.padding', {
                    'sticky': 'nswe',
                    'children': [(
                        'Entry.textarea', {
                            'sticky': 'nswe'})]
                })]
        })]
})]
```

...and if we replace a `field` with `border` element in this structure, the appearence is very close to your demands (also try `groove` relief in this case):

[image: vista]

### Conclusion:

Unfortunately, this widget will lack options of field and border color, so another option is [create own element](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.element_create) for this purpose, but that is another question.

So, basicly I tryied to answer not *"how to workaround this"*, but *"why a relief has no effect on Entry"*, anyway as you can see, a flat relief for an Entry is achievable.