# Can I use two different TTK themes in one Tkinter (tk.Tk) root window?

Tags: python, tkinter

This question concerns Python and Tkinter.

I'd like to use two different ttk themes simultaneously, e.g. 'clam' and 'vista' in one Tkinter window. So I wrote this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        Button_v1()
        Button_v2()


class Button_v1(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, default_text="Test"):

        super().__init__(text=default_text)

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.theme_use('clam')
        s.configure(self.winfo_class(), foreground='blue')
        self.pack()


class Button_v2(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, default_text="Test2"):

        super().__init__(text=default_text)

        s2 = ttk.Style()
        s2.theme_use('vista')
        s2.configure(self.winfo_class(), foreground='red')
        self.pack()


GUI().mainloop()
```

The code loads, however:

1. I expected the first Button's foreground to be blue and the second Button's foreground to be red, and for two separate themes to be used.
2. Instead, both buttons have a red foreground, and both apply the same theme.

Is it possible to use two separate ttk themes in one Tkinter program?

Comment: You can't do that. But, you can change it at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible, because `theme` has a global meaning in this context. You can represent `theme` as a set of styles for widgets ([for widget layout elements, actually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385810/6634373)), you can change style and/or create a new one, but you can't use more than one of themes at the time, because widget's layout depends heavily on it.

When you call `theme_use('theme_name')` tkinter rebuilds all widget's layouts and [redraws your entire application](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.theme_use), and you can easily check this, thanks to `<<ThemeChanged>>` virtual event.

Here's a snippet. You will see three prints, caused by each button and by root himself.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bind('<<ThemeChanged>>', lambda event: print('theme changed in root and across all widgets!'))
        Button_v1()
        Button_v2()


class Button_v1(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, default_text="Test"):
        super().__init__(text=default_text)
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.theme_use('clam')
        s.configure(self.winfo_class(), foreground='blue')
        self.pack()


class Button_v2(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, default_text="Test2"):
        super().__init__(text=default_text)
        s2 = ttk.Style()
        s2.theme_use('vista')
        s2.configure(self.winfo_class(), foreground='red')
        self.pack()

GUI().mainloop()
```

If you need different foreground for each button - [then create a new](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html) `style` for each of them and use the `style` parameter:

Here's an another snippet:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('blue.TButton', foreground='blue')
        s.configure('red.TButton', foreground='red')

        Button_v1()
        Button_v2()


class Button_v1(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, default_text="Test"):
        super().__init__(text=default_text, style='blue.TButton')
        self.pack()


class Button_v2(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, default_text="Test2"):
        super().__init__(text=default_text, style='red.TButton')
        self.pack()

GUI().mainloop()
```

Everything is well described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style) and [there](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use two different themes at the same time.

From the canonical documentation [[1]](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_style.htm#M17) for the function underlying the `theme_use` method (emphasis added by me):

> Without an argument the result is the name of the current theme. Otherwise this command sets the current theme to themeName, and **refreshes all widgets.**

Here is a simple example showing how you can switch themes on the fly:

```
# python  2
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

# python 3
#import tkinter as tk
#import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def switch_theme(theme):
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use(theme)

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
for theme in style.theme_names():
    button = ttk.Button(root, text=theme,
                        command=lambda theme=theme: switch_theme(theme))
    button.pack(side="top", padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. Further, in the above code, the foreground colours of the Buttons do not change -- they are _both_ red, even though they are based on two different styles (labelled as `s` and `s2`) and supposedly coloured red/blue. Does this mean that every Tkinter program can only use _one_ set of styles?

Comment: @anonnoir: no, you can switch between styles. You can only use one at a time, but you can switch them at runtime.

Comment: I see. So that means I can 'stock' two or three different styles (with variations of `s=ttk.Style()`), and activate them on the occurrence of events? I didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't use two different themes. But, you can create a style:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="black", background="white")

l1 = ttk.Label(text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
l2 = ttk.Label(text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
```

You can create another style for a different widget