# Python Tkinter Entry input and placing Placeholder

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python Tkinter and got an error saying that "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-borderwidth". When I remove the borderwidth there is a border around the entry box. I don't want any border around it. Is there a way so that there is no border? and how can I only make the placeholder to be gray and the text to be black.

Please see below code. I am using this code so that there is a placeholder in the entry box and if I click it the placeholder is remove and I click it again. Thank you

```
class PlaceholderEntry(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, container, placeholder, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, *args, style="Placeholder.TEntry", **kwargs)
        self.placeholder = placeholder

        self.insert("0", self.placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self._clear_placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self._add_placeholder)

    def _clear_placeholder(self, e):
        if self["style"] == "Placeholder.TEntry":
            self.delete("0", "end")
            self["style"] = "TEntry"

    def _add_placeholder(self, e):
        if not self.get():
            self.insert("0", self.placeholder)
            self["style"] = "Placeholder.TEntry"

self.user_input = PlaceholderEntry(root, 'USERNAME OR EMAIL', font=("Corbel", 15), 
foreground="#d5d5d5", borderwidth="0")
self.user_input.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.455, width=300, height=24)
```

Comment: You can't change the borderwith of a ttk entry (to my knowledge). Also in your own code you set the style of the entry to "Placeholder.TEntry" and then passed in arguments like foreground and others. Just define the style and all of them will follow it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(took some help from [How to get FLAT relief Entry widget in python ttk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383730/how-to-get-flat-relief-entry-widget-in-python-ttk))

```
class PlaceholderEntry(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, container, placeholder, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, *args, style="Placeholder.TEntry", **kwargs)
        self.placeholder = placeholder

        self.insert("0", self.placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self._clear_placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self._add_placeholder)

    def _clear_placeholder(self, e):
        if self["style"] == "Placeholder.TEntry":
            self.delete("0", "end")
            self["foreground"]="#000000"

    def _add_placeholder(self, e):
        if not self.get():
            self.insert("0", self.placeholder)
            self["foreground"]="#d5d5d5"

#   declare style variable
s = ttk.Style()
#   assume that classic theme in use
s.theme_use('classic')

#   configure relief
s.configure('Placeholder.TEntry', relief='flat', background="white")
#   lets try to change this structure

s.layout('Placeholder.TEntry', [
    ('Entry.highlight', {
        'sticky': 'nswe',
        'children':
            [('Entry.border', {
                'border': '0',
                'sticky': 'nswe',
                'children':
                    [('Entry.padding', {
                        'sticky': 'nswe',
                        'children':
                            [('Entry.textarea',
                              {'sticky': 'nswe'})]
                    })]
            })]
    })])

self.user_input = PlaceholderEntry(root, 'USERNAME OR EMAIL', font=("Corbel", 15), foreground="#d5d5d5")
self.user_input.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.455, width=300, height=24)
```