# How to remove blue border of a button in tkinter on macOS?

Tags: python, tkinter, border

I want to remove the blue border of button when a user clicks on it. There is no blue border when i use the normal tkinter button, i'm using tkmacosx button through which i can change its background color but it has a blue border around it.

This is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkmacosx as tkm
root = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Submit')
b1.pack()
b2 = tkm.Button(root, text='Submit', bg='#ADEFD1', borderless=1)
b2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Photo 1: I want the button to look like this even after the user clicks on it without any border.**

[image: I want the button to look like this even after the user clicks on it without any border.]

**Photo 2: I get this after the user clicks on it.**

[image: I get this after the user clicks on it.]

How can i remove or hide the blue border?

Please help thank you

Comment: try tk.Button(root, text='exampel',bd=0)

Comment: @Atlas435: I tried bd=0 and that did not do anything

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47156214/13629335

Comment: That is something else @Atlas435. i want to remove the blue focus border line around the button, please see my images.

Comment: and normally you do it like I said. Not sure what is the issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990704/how-get-no-border-effect-in-tkinter-ttk

Comment: @Atlas435, In photo 1, there is no blue border but in photo 2, there is, so can i remove or hide it permanently.

Comment: You can set `takefocus=0` or `focuscolor=''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Saad answer I have solved my issue and completely removed the focus button border. Just configure `takefocus` as 0.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkmacosx as tkm

root = tk.Tk()
tkm.Button(root, text='Submit', bg='#ADEFD1', borderless=1, takefocus=0).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Big Sur (11.0.1)

- `takefocus=0` doesn't work
- `focuscolor=''` works perfectly.